# Ruby: character to ascii from a string

Tags: ruby, ascii

this wiki page gave a general idea of how to convert a single char to ascii http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/ASCII

But say if I have a string and I wanted to get each character's ascii from it, what do i need to do?

```
"string".each_byte do |c|
      $char = c.chr
      $ascii = ?char
      puts $ascii
end
```

It doesn't work because it's not happy with the line $ascii = ?char

```
syntax error, unexpected '?'
      $ascii = ?char
                ^
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `c` variable already contains the char code!

```
"string".each_byte do |c|
    puts c
end
```

yields

```
115
116
114
105
110
103
```

Answer (score 22):

```
puts "string".split('').map(&:ord).to_s
```

Comment: even nicer than `split('')` is calling `chars`

Answer (score 14):

Ruby String provides the `codepoints` method after 1.9.1.

```
str = 'hello world'
str.codepoints
=> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100] 

str = "你好世界"
str.codepoints
=> [20320, 22909, 19990, 30028]
```

Comment: do you actually need the `.to_a` after codepoints? Seems like `codepoints` already returns an array `"abcde".codepoints.class #=> Array`

Answer (score 12):

use "x".ord for a single character or "xyz".sum for a whole string.

Answer (score 8):

please refer to this post for the changes in ruby1.9 [Getting an ASCII character code in Ruby using `?` (question mark) fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270209/getting-an-ascii-character-code-in-ruby-fails)

Answer (score 8):

You could also just call to_a after each_byte or even better String#bytes

```
=> 'hello world'.each_byte.to_a
=> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]

=> 'hello world'.bytes
=> [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"a"[0]
```

or

```
?a
```

Both would return their ASCII equivalent.

Comment: Did this change in Ruby 1.9 ?

Comment: Yea, in Ruby 1.8 it return the characters ascii value, but it ruby the character at the index in ruby 1.9...

Comment: `"a"[0].ord` should return the ascii code. Note that it's actually a unicode code.