# Ruby 1.9.x undefined method ^ for string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.2

i found a ruby encryption library which is using this function.

```
def process(text)  
  0.upto(text.length-1) {|i| text[i] = text[i] ^ round}  
  text  
end
```

in ruby 1.9.x it throws an error - `undefined method ^' for "\x1A":String__`

is there any work around in ruby 1.9.x?

after googling i came to know that "**In Ruby 1.9 string[index] returns character not code of the character (like it was in 1.8).**"  (https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3144-undefined-method-for-string-ror-234)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `text.each_byte.map { |b| (b ^ round).chr }.join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `text[i].ord ^ round`.  See [Getting an ASCII character code in Ruby using `?` (question mark) fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270209/getting-an-ascii-character-code-in-ruby-fails) for more info.

Comment: TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String  
 from (irb):90:in `[]='  
 from (irb):90:in `block in irb_binding'  
 from (irb):90:in `upto'  
 from (irb):90

Comment: @Krishnaprasad, in that case you might try running `to_s` on the result of `text[i] ^ round`