# ASCII value of character in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ascii, character

How do I obtain the ASCII value of a character in Ruby 1.9?

I searched the Internet far and wide, but without success. 
I tried ?x and "x"[0], but all they return is "x".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an ascii character code in ruby - ? fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270209/getting-an-ascii-character-code-in-ruby-fails)

Comment: "I searched the Internet far and wide, but without success.". Hmm. The [search engines](http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+1.9+character+ordinal+value) must have had a bad day.

Comment: @the Tin Man: Maybe the OP didn't know the word "ordinal".

Comment: @Andrew Grimm - sigh... now I know my place in life. I find things for others.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The [`String#ord`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/String.html#M000257) method will do the trick:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 > 'x'.ord
 => 120 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 > '0'.ord
 => 48 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 > ' '.ord
 => 32
```

Answer (score 16):

You can also use

```
ruby-2.0.0p353 > "x".sum
=> 120

ruby-2.0.0p353 > "a string".sum
=> 792
```

The 'sum' method will find the sum of all character codes, but if you put only one character it will give you the code of that one only.

Comment: It also seems that .ord needs correct UTF-8 but that .sum does not care.

Comment: 0.ord will work, returning 0, the ascii value. However, 0.sum will not, it returns undefined method for Fixnum.

Comment: This doesn't give correct results for Unicode characters: `"€".ord => 8364`, while `"€".sum => 528`

Answer (score 7):

```
x.ord
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001177

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck with this: `ord` returns the ASCII value for a given character, but I wanted to obtain the character for a given ASCII value. The solution is `ascii_value.chr`.