# How to convert a document into ASCII?

Tags: ruby, text, character-encoding, ascii

So, for example you have a document: Ruby.txt, the contents of which are

> RuBYrUbYRuByByurBRyuRuby

You for some reason need to convert the document's contents into ASCII code **without** printing it onto your screen (change the document's contents).
How do you do that?

P.S. Sorry, no code to debug

Comment: Do you actually mean you want to print the ASCII character codes? It may already *be* in ASCII.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an ascii character code in ruby - ? fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270209/getting-an-ascii-character-code-in-ruby-fails)

Comment: @dave I meant binary code (e.g. 01,10,11,00,101011001110101000110011...)

Comment: You mean *binary* then, a different question. If this is homework, please tag as such. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing... and what do you mean by "homework"

Answer (score 0):

```
"RuBYrUbYRuByByurBRyuRuby".unpack("c*")
 => [82, 117, 66, 89, 114, 85, 98, 89, 82, 117, 66, 121, 66, 121, 117, 114, 66, 82, 121, 117, 82, 117, 98, 121]
```

Comment: "ruby".unpack("b*")
 => ["01001110101011100100011010011110"]

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on your ruby version...
but this should work on both 1.8 and 1.9

```
1.9.3p194 :062 > "string".each_byte do |c|
1.9.3p194 :063 >     puts c.ord
1.9.3p194 :064?>   end
115
116
114
105
110
103
 => "string"
```