# Convert a string of text (user input) to binary

Tags: ruby, text, binary

I basically need to get user input:

```
gets.chomp("input?")
```

And then to convert the given input to binary.

That's the part I don't get. :(

Comment: What do you mean convert to binary? Convert to a binary int representation? Pack into some kind of byte stream?

Comment: or rather, "Hello!" would be 01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100001

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143822/ruby-character-to-ascii-from-a-string

Comment: @CodeGnome No. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: stan, are these homework questions?

Comment: @DGM What do you mean "homework questions"?

Comment: your two questions so far look suspiciously like school homework and should be tagged as such

Comment: Homework for whom? you or me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
a = gets.chomp
puts a.each_byte.map {|y| sprintf "%08b", y}.join " "
```

Comment: This is unsatisfactory: it doesn't zero pad, or space, so you get a stream of digits, but it's impossible to reassemble the original meaningfully.

Comment: @Len you are almost a ruby god